# Как вращать объекты в opengl по трём осям одновременно?

Tags: c++, opengl

У меня есть 3 угла, по каждой из осей в градусах. Нужно повернуть объект на эти углы относительно изначального положения объекта. Что я делаю:

```
glm::vec4 rot0 = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.0f };
```

при некоторых условиях значения углов меняются в диапазоне [-180..180)

```
rot0.w = glm::max(glm::max(glm::abs(rot0.x),glm::abs(rot0.y)), glm::abs(rot0.z));
            if (rot0.w)
            modelMat4 = glm::rotate(modelMat4, glm::radians(rot0.w),
                glm::vec3(
                    glm::radians(rot0.x / rot0.w),
                    glm::radians(rot0.y / rot0.w),
                    glm::radians(rot0.z / rot0.w)
                )
            );
```

В такой ситуации объект вращается не так, как я того ожидал. Он вращается так, будто rotate вызвано несколько раз подряд для каждой оси отдельно. А я бы хотел одним вызовом rotate установить объект нужным образом. Как это можно сделать?

дополнительно создал вектор для углов в радианах:

```
rad0 = { glm::radians(rot0.x) ,glm::radians(rot0.y) ,glm::radians(rot0.z) };
```

теперь создаю матрицу и сразу умножаю на матрицу модели так:

```
glm::quat q = glm::quat(rad0);
            modelMat4 *= glm::toMat4(q);
```

вращаться стало плавно, без резких разворотов на 180 и без рывков.
при повороте по Х дальнейший поворот по Y отрабатывает правильно.
при повороте по Х дальнейший поворот по Z отрабатывает правильно.
при повороте по Y дальнейший поворот по Z отрабатывает правильно.
при повороте по Y дальнейший поворот по X отрабатывает НЕ правильно.
при повороте по Z дальнейший поворот по Y отрабатывает НЕ правильно.
при повороте по Z дальнейший поворот по X отрабатывает НЕ правильно.
Где "правильным" я называю поворот относительно начальной оси координат, а неправильным поворот вокруг чего-то иного.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Дух сообщества в таком виде если, например, повернуть объект на 180 по оси Y, то при попытке дальнейшего вращения вокруг оси Х он будет вращаться уже по оси Z (визуально). Т.е. оси координат были изменены, а мне нужно относительно изначальной системы координат.

Comment: Это т.н. Gimbal lock - когда поворот по одной из осей на 90гр делает невозможным возможность поворота по другой оси. Лечится изменением порядка поворотов, либо неиспользованием таких углов, либо переходом к кватернионам.

Comment: Стоит сразу разобраться с кватернионами.

Comment: @user7860670 "переход на квантерионы" не решил проблему. теперь нет блокировок, нет ситуаций когда совсем не крутится, когда резко разворачивается зеркально. но при одновременном повороте по Y и по X вместо X крутится по Z временами. сделал так:  glm::quat q = glm::quat(rad0);
            modelMat4 *= glm::toMat4(q);, где rad0 -- это glm::vec3 с углами в радианах

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации, умножай матрицы в другом порядке. :) `modelMat4 = glm::toMat4(q) * modelMat4;`. Если не помогло, то давайте конкретный пример с числами: что в какую сторону поворачивается, и куда должно поворачиваться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat конкретный пример: когда угол по Z равен 180/-180, то вращение вокруг X или вокруг Y идёт ровно в обратную сторону. Когда угол по Y 180/-180, то вращение по X идёт ровно в обратную сторону. Порядок умножения правильный, мне нужно вращать после смещения.

Comment: Вроде понял. `glm::quat(vec3)` конструирует из трех углов эйлера. А у вас вообще нигде не должны храниться тройки углов, везде только кватернионы.

Comment: Или, сформулирую по-другому. *"угол по Z равен 180/-180"* - это должен быть один кватернион, а *"вращение вокруг X или вокруг Y"* - другой кватернион, на который умножается первый.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пока что я не представляю, как можно хранить угол поворота по каждой оси в отдельном кватернионе, и как с ними взаимодействовать, чтобы вращать объект. Судя по тому, что вращение при 180 идёт в обратную сторону, а при 90 вокруг "другой" оси, здесь на вход нужно подавать не просто угол в радианах, но и умножать на косинусы/синусы по другим осям. пока "ничего не понятно, но очень интересно".

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Смотрите, вам для вашего объекта нужно хранить один кватернион, а не тройку углов. Чтобы повернуть объект, домножаете этот кватернион на другой. *"умножать на косинусы/синусы по другим осям"* Вот этого руками делать не надо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat можно подробнее, пожалуйста? создаю "пустую" переменную: glm::quat q(); дальше я хочу "повернуть на 180 вокруг оси X". Т.е. мне нужно создать ещё один glm::quat и на него умножить, причём в порядке "старый" * "новый". Это понятно. Но как мне создать кватернион, который содержит "вращать на А вокруг Н"? И я не понял, как при этом обойтись без углов Эйлера.

Comment: Не могу найти в glm нужный конструктор. Вручную так: `glm::quat(std::cos(a/2), std::sin(a/2)*x, std::sin(a/2)*y, std::sin(a/2)*z)`, где - `a` - угол, а `x,y,z` - нормализовнная ось (т.е. длиной 1).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
поменял на следующее: `glm::quat q(glm::mat4(1.f));
            q *= glm::quat(std::cos(rad0.x/ 2), std::sin(rad0.x / 2), 0, 0);
            q *= glm::quat(std::cos(rad0.y / 2), 0, std::sin(rad0.y / 2), 0);
            q *= glm::quat(std::cos(rad0.z / 2),0,0, std::sin(rad0.z / 2));
            modelMat4 *= glm::toMat4(q);` теперь вращается иначе, но всё ещё не так, как ожидалось. Теперь если угол по Х = 90, то попытка вращения вокруг Y приводит к вращению вокруг Z.

Comment: Я еще раз повторю. Вы не должны хранить тройку углов. Вы должны хранить только кватернион.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тогда я совершенно не понимаю, как с ним работать. Допустим, я не буду каждый кадр "обнулять" кватернион, а буду исходя из событий умножать его на "шаг". Но это не решает проблему, что вращение не в ту сторону, это лишь уменьшит количество переменных в коде. Сейчас при увеличении угла по Х текстурированный квадрат "падает" верхней частью на меня. При этом когда угол по Y=180 (повёрнут ко мне "спиной"), то ожидается, что при увеличении по Х он будет верхней частью "падать" от меня, но он продолжает "падать" на меня.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat всё ещё не особо понял, как это работает, но получил хоть какое-то предсказуемое поведение, когда инициализировал так: `glm::quat(1.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);`, с этим уже можно работать. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: *"это не решает проблему, что вращение не в ту сторону"* Как раз-таки должно решить. Если после перехода на кватернион останется та проблема, про которую вы говорили, значит нужно просто умножать кватернионы в другом порядке.

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat
Можно как-то "быстро" вытащить из кватерниона угол относительно одной из осей, точнее косинус и синус? Если мне нужно подвинуть объект по XY, но не относительно начала координат, а с учётом его поворота вокруг оси Z. Т.е. длину смещения по X и Y нужно умножать на синусы/косинусы вращения вокруг Z.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно для вращения использовать glm::rotate с углами, чтобы не иметь радость, когда модель неожиданно отзеркаливается относительно какой-либо плоскости.
Нужно создать "пустой" кватернион **именно** вида **{1,0,0,0}** и уже его умножать на всё остальное, матрицу умножать на кватернион.
В этом и была вся суть. Теперь точки вращаются предсказуемо вокруг {0,0,0} относительно своих локальных координат и оригинальных осей. glm::quat -- это кватернион, представленный, грубо говоря, как массив из 4х переменных типа float.

Comment: осталось придумать, как устанавливать объект по 3 углам относительно глобальных координат и относительно камеры, но это уже совсем другая история